# Mapping multiple fields to one in Mapstruct?

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I need to map from an open banking class to my core class. I am working with `mapstruct`. I need to map multiple enum fields to one on my core class. But i think mapstruct doesn't support mapping multiple fields. Any tricky way or a solution for that?
Thanks in advance!
Here is my enum values from open banking:

```java
public enum Category {

  TRANS_AND_SAVINGS_ACCOUNTS("TRANS_AND_SAVINGS_ACCOUNTS"),  
  REGULATED_TRUST_ACCOUNTS("REGULATED_TRUST_ACCOUNTS"),  
  CRED_AND_CHRG_CARDS("CRED_AND_CHRG_CARDS"),  
  PERS_LOANS("PERS_LOANS"),  
  MARGIN_LOANS("MARGIN_LOANS"),  
  PROPERTY_LOANS("PROPERTY_LOANS"),  
  TRADE_FINANCE("TRADE_FINANCE"),  
  OVERDRAFTS("OVERDRAFTS"),  
  BUSINESS_LOANS("BUSINESS_LOANS"),
  RESIDENTIAL_MORTGAGES("RESIDENTIAL_MORTGAGES");

...

}
```

And here is my core class:

```java
    public enum Type{

        CHARGES( "Charges" ),
        CREDITS( "Credits" ),
        ALL_LOANS( "AllLoans" ),
        MORTGAGE( "Mortgage" ),
        OTHER( "Other" ),
        PREPAIDCARD( "PrePaidCard" ),
        SAVINGS( "Savings" );

...

}
```

And i have a `valueMapping` as following(which is wrong):

```java
public interface TypeMapper {
    @ValueMappings( {
            @ValueMapping(source = "CHARGES", target= "CRED_AND_CHRG_CARDS"),
            @ValueMapping(source = "CREDITS", target= "CRED_AND_CHRG_CARDS"),
            @ValueMapping(source = "ALL_LOANS", target = "PERS_LOANS"),
            @ValueMapping(source = "ALL_LOANS", target = "MARGIN_LOANS"),
            @ValueMapping(source = "ALL_LOANS", target = "BUSINESS_LOANS"),
            @ValueMapping(source = "ALL_LOANS", target = "PROPERTY_LOANS"),
            @ValueMapping(source = "MORTGAGE", target= "RESIDENTIAL_MORTGAGES"),
            @ValueMapping(source = "OTHER", target= "OVERDRAFTS"),
            @ValueMapping(source = "PREPAIDCARD", target = MappingConstants.NULL),
            @ValueMapping(source = "SAVINGS", target = "TRANS_AND_SAVINGS_ACCOUNTS")
    } )

...

}
```

It does not accept to map `PERS_LOANS("PERS_LOANS"), MARGIN_LOANS("MARGIN_LOANS"), PROPERTY_LOANS("PROPERTY_LOANS")` to `ALL_LOANS`. I wonder if there's a way to map all 3 to one field. Maybe can it be covered in `@AfterMapping`, any suggestions? And i want to map all the unmapped values to `OTHER` in my core class.

Comment: could it be you flipped `source` and `target`? You try to map "ALL_LOANS" to 4 different targets..

Comment: small note: you could skip the plural `@ValueMappings` in java8 making your mapping (a little) more compact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you are saying that you can't map `PERS_LOANS`, `MARGIN_LOANS`, etc. to `ALL_LOANS`. However, your value mappings are reversed. You are mapping `ALL_LOANS` to `PERS_LOANS`.

It is not possible to map one enum (source) value to multiple enum (target) values. However, it is possible to map multiple enum (source) values to the same enum (target) value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement it by yourself, because MapStruct doesn't support that. Try to use `@qualifiedByName` annotation with your own method

For example:

```
public interface TypeMapper{
    @Mapping(target= "CRED_AND_CHRG_CARDS", qualifiedByName = "creditAndChrgCardsMapping")
    public Type CategoryToType(Category category);
    
    default String qualifiedByName (String charges, String credits){
    //Implement your business logic for example
    return charges + credits;
    } 
 }
```